# Index Won't appear in an arabic document

Tags: indexing, arabic, xindy, right-to-left

I am making a book, and using Polyglossia package along with biblatex and XELATEX. I am using Arabic and English languages. When I try to make an index, it won't appear. Here is the code as shown below:
(In ORDER TO RUN the CODE: DOWNLOAD the FONT SIMPLIFIED ARABIC and INSTALL IT IN WINDOWS USING THE FOLLOWING LINK:
https://www.wfonts.com/font/simplified-arabic)

```
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,margin=2.5cm,bindingoffset=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{showidx}
\usepackage[xindy]{imakeidx}

\usepackage{polyglossia} 
\setdefaultlanguage{arabic} 
\setotherlanguages{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Mapping=arabicdigits]{Simplified Arabic} %  


\title{}
\author{}
\date{}

\makeindex[program=texindy]
\begin{document}
\chapter{sdfdsdf}
يبسيبسيب
\section{Introduction}
سيسيبسيب
\index{سيبيبسسيب}

\begin{english}
In this example several keywords\textenglish{\index{keywords}} will be used 
which are important and deserve to appear in the Index\index{Index}.

Terms like generate\index{generate} and some\index{others} will 
also show up.
\end{english}

\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you find the answer?

Comment: Nope, but I stopped using Xelatex and swiched to Babel + lualatex + biblatex